# Query objects from a Many to Many look-up table

Tags: .net, sql, join, subsonic, many-to-many

I have `Master1` and `Sub1` and a another called `Master1Sub1_Map` which contains foreign keys to the `Master1` and `Sub1` objects.  There are multiple ID's from `Sub1` that are associated with a single id in `Master1`.

If I want to see all the `Sub1` records that are assigned to a specific `Master1.ID` how do I go about doing that with the SubSonic objects?  I can do it using SqlQuery and `IN` with a nested select, but is there a better way since the map table is using foreign keys?  It would be nice to have a Sub1Collection returned.

I see some references in `TableSchema` but I am not sure what will do what I am looking for.

Comment: you should have tagged your question with "subsonic"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub1Collection subs = DB.Select().From<Sub1>()  
  .InnerJoin(Master1Sub1_Map)  
  .InnerJoin(Master1)  
  .Where(Master1.Columns.Id).IsEqualTo(1)  
  .ExecuteAsCollection<Sub1Collection>();
```